# Clearing Print in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm pretty new to both coding and this website, so please bear with me if this is stupid:

I'm working on a personal project and would like to find a way to clear "print()" statements in python 3.6. For example:

```
print("The user would see this text.")
```

but if I continue

```
print("The user would see this text.")
print("They would also see this text.")
```

Is there a way to make it so a user would only see the second print statement?

I have seen "os.system('cls')" and "os.system('clear')" recommended, but I get these errors for each:

```
os.system('cls')
```

resulting in

sh: 1: cls: not found

and

```
os.system('clear')
```

resulting in

TERM environment variable not set.

Obviously I'm missing something, but if you know what it'd be much appreciated. If you know of another way to do what I'm thinking, that would also be awesome. Thank you for taking the time to read this, and thanks for any help.

Edit: I'm using Repl.it as my IDE. Could this be an issue with that site specifically?

Edit: Downloaded a new IDE to check, and the reply worked. If you are new and using Repl.it, be aware that some code does not function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that I've used in the past to 'reprint' something on an existing line is to make use of the standard output directly, coupled with a carriage return to bring the printed statement's cursor back to the start of the line (`\r` = carriage return), instead of relying on the print function.

**In pseudocode:**

```
# Send what you want to print initially to standard output, with a carriage return appended to the front of it.  
# Flush the contents of standard output.    
# Send the second thing you want to print to standard output.
```

**A working example in Python:**

```
import sys  

sys.stdout.write('\rThe user would see this text')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write('\rThe user would also see this text')
```

**Edit**
Figured I'd add an example where you can actually see the code working, since the working example above is going to execute so quickly that you'll never see the original line. The below code incorporates a sleep so that you can see it print the first line, wait, then reprint the line using the second string:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

sys.stdout.write('\rThe user would see this text')
sys.stdout.flush()

sleep(2)

sys.stdout.write('\rThe user would also see this text')
```